# Easiest way to convert a TableRow to JSON-formatted String, in dataflow 2.x?

Tags: java, json, apache-beam, dataflow

Short of writing my own function to do it, what is the easiest way to convert a `TableRow` object, inside a dataflow 2.x pipeline, to a JSON-formatted String?

I thought the code below would work, but it isn't correctly inserting quotes in between key/values, especially where there are nested fields.

```
public static class TableRowToString extends DoFn<TableRow, String> {    
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  @ProcessElement
    public void processElement(ProcessContext c) {
      c.output(c.element().toString());
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `GSON` and do a `gson.toJson(yourTableRow)` details [here](https://github.com/bomboradata/pubsub-to-bigquery/blob/master/src/main/java/com/bombora/pubsub/to/bq/PrepData.java)

Answer (score 4):

I ran into the same problem, I solved by using [org.apache.beam.sdk.extensions.jackson.AsJsons](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.5.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/extensions/jackson/AsJsons.html).

To use it, it is not necessary to create a new transform, you can apply it directly on the pipeline.

```
import org.apache.beam.sdk.extensions.jackson.AsJsons;

Pipeline p = Pipeline.create(options);

p.apply("The transform that returns a PCollection of TableRow")
.apply("JSon Transform", AsJsons.of(TableRow.class));
```

---

And if you are managing your project with maven, you can add this to the `<dependencies>` in the `pom.xml` file

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
  <artifactId>beam-sdks-java-extensions-json-jackson</artifactId>
  <version>2.5.0</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: This is interesting. I wonder what the efficiency of AsJsons is? But comparison, we have found that Gson is very expensive to use; At this point we try to use it exclusively in unit tests to transform JSON strings into objects for use as inputs.

Comment: I am running samples with a 100 TableRows and about 20 columns so I can't say much about the efficiency right now.

Comment: Update about the efficiency: I ran the Json Transform for 142,515,724 TableRows and it took 14 min 22 sec on dataflow

Comment: What's the return value of the `AsJsons` transform? is it like `PCollection<what??>`?

Comment: @bigbounty looking at the documentation, `AsJsons.of` returns a `PCollection<ObjectMapper> `

_Creates a AsJsons PTransform that will transform a PCollection<InputT> into a PCollection of JSON Strings representing those objects using a Jackson ObjectMapper._

https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.0.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/extensions/jackson/AsJsons.html#of-java.lang.Class-

Comment: It should `PCollection<String>` right? Because the docs say JSON ***Strings***

Comment: You are probably right, but I do not have the environment test this anymore

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to use similar set up where I am trying to convert beam `Row` instead of `TableRow`

Like below:

`PCollection<String> jsonStrings = result.apply("RowToJSON", AsJsons.of(Row.class));`

But What I rather get is complete JSON object; schema with fields

`{
"schema": {
"encodingPositions": {
"drug_name": 0,
"eid": 1,
"generic_id": 9,
"patientid": 4,
"docid": 2,
"therapeutic_class": 7,
"generic_name": 6,
"prid": 3,
"created_at": 10,
"source": 11,
"updated_ekaid": 5,
"disease_name": 8
},
"encodingPositionsOverridden": false,
"fields": [
{
"name": "drug_name",
"description": "",
"type": {
"typeName": "STRING",
"nullable": false,
"logicalType": null,
"collectionElementType": null,
"mapKeyType": null,
"mapValueType": null,
"rowSchema": null,
"allMetadata": {

```
      }
    },
    "options": {
      "optionNames": [
        
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "name": "eid",
    "description": "",
    "type": {
      "typeName": "STRING",
      "nullable": false,
      "logicalType": null,
      "collectionElementType": null,
      "mapKeyType": null,
      "mapValueType": null,
      "rowSchema": null,
      "allMetadata": {
        
      }
    },
    "options": {
      "optionNames": [
        
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "name": "docid",
    "description": "",
    "type": {
      "typeName": "STRING",
      "nullable": false,
      "logicalType": null,
      "collectionElementType": null,
      "mapKeyType": null,
      "mapValueType": null,
      "rowSchema": null,
      "allMetadata": {
        
      }
    },
    "options": {
      "optionNames": [
        
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "name": "prid",
    "description": "",
    "type": {
      "typeName": "STRING",
      "nullable": false,
      "logicalType": null,
      "collectionElementType": null,
      "mapKeyType": null,
      "mapValueType": null,
      "rowSchema": null,
      "allMetadata": {
        
      }
    },
    "options": {
      "optionNames": [
        
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "name": "patientid",
    "description": "",
    "type": {
      "typeName": "STRING",
      "nullable": false,
      "logicalType": null,
      "collectionElementType": null,
      "mapKeyType": null,
      "mapValueType": null,
      "rowSchema": null,
      "allMetadata": {
        
      }
    },
    "options": {
      "optionNames": [
        
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "name": "updated_ekaid",
    "description": "",
    "type": {
      "typeName": "STRING",
      "nullable": true,
      "logicalType": null,
      "collectionElementType": null,
      "mapKeyType": null,
      "mapValueType": null,
      "rowSchema": null,
      "allMetadata": {
        
      }
    },
    "options": {
      "optionNames": [
        
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "name": "generic_name",
    "description": "",
    "type": {
      "typeName": "STRING",
      "nullable": true,
      "logicalType": null,
      "collectionElementType": null,
      "mapKeyType": null,
      "mapValueType": null,
      "rowSchema": null,
      "allMetadata": {
        
      }
    },
    "options": {
      "optionNames": [
        
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "name": "therapeutic_class",
    "description": "",
    "type": {
      "typeName": "STRING",
      "nullable": true,
      "logicalType": null,
      "collectionElementType": null,
      "mapKeyType": null,
      "mapValueType": null,
      "rowSchema": null,
      "allMetadata": {
        
      }
    },
    "options": {
      "optionNames": [
        
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "name": "disease_name",
    "description": "",
    "type": {
      "typeName": "STRING",
      "nullable": true,
      "logicalType": null,
      "collectionElementType": null,
      "mapKeyType": null,
      "mapValueType": null,
      "rowSchema": null,
      "allMetadata": {
        
      }
    },
    "options": {
      "optionNames": [
        
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "name": "generic_id",
    "description": "",
    "type": {
      "typeName": "STRING",
      "nullable": true,
      "logicalType": null,
      "collectionElementType": null,
      "mapKeyType": null,
      "mapValueType": null,
      "rowSchema": null,
      "allMetadata": {
        
      }
    },
    "options": {
      "optionNames": [
        
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "name": "created_at",
    "description": "",
    "type": {
      "typeName": "STRING",
      "nullable": false,
      "logicalType": null,
      "collectionElementType": null,
      "mapKeyType": null,
      "mapValueType": null,
      "rowSchema": null,
      "allMetadata": {
        
      }
    },
    "options": {
      "optionNames": [
        
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "name": "source",
    "description": "",
    "type": {
      "typeName": "LOGICAL_TYPE",
      "nullable": false,
      "logicalType": {
        "identifier": "SqlCharType",
        "argumentType": {
          "typeName": "STRING",
          "nullable": false,
          "logicalType": null,
          "collectionElementType": null,
          "mapKeyType": null,
          "mapValueType": null,
          "rowSchema": null,
          "allMetadata": {
            
          }
        },
        "argument": "",
        "baseType": {
          "typeName": "STRING",
          "nullable": false,
          "logicalType": null,
          "collectionElementType": null,
          "mapKeyType": null,
          "mapValueType": null,
          "rowSchema": null,
          "allMetadata": {
            
          }
        }
      },
      "collectionElementType": null,
      "mapKeyType": null,
      "mapValueType": null,
      "rowSchema": null,
      "allMetadata": {
        
      }
    },
    "options": {
      "optionNames": [
        
      ]
    }
  }
],
"uuid": null,
"options": {
  "optionNames": [
    
  ]
},
"fieldNames": [
  "drug_name",
  "eid",
  "docid",
  "prid",
  "patientid",
  "updated_ekaid",
  "generic_name",
  "therapeutic_class",
  "disease_name",
  "generic_id",
  "created_at",
  "source"
],
"fieldCount": 12
```

},
"values": [
"drug_name",
"mid",
"did",
"prid",
"pid",
"bid",
"medicineclassname",
"medicine class",
"['disease name']",
"genericid",
"2023-10-13",
"current_medications"
],
"fieldCount": 12,
"baseValues": [
"drug_name",
"mid",
"did",
"prid",
"pid",
"bid",
"medicineclassname",
"medicine class",
"['disease name']",
"genericid",
"2023-10-13",
"current_medications"
]
}`

Whereas I am expecting

`{"drug_name": "drug_name", "eid": "mid", "docid": "did", "prid": "prid", "patientid": "pid", "updated_ekaid": "bid", "generic_name": "medicineclassname", "therapeutic_class": "medicine class", "disease_name": "[\'disease name\']", "generic_id": "genericid", "created_at": "2023-10-13", "source": "current_medications"}`

How to achieve the desired only Values as JSON ?